# Activity started with startActivityForResult() not returning to calling Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 Activities - **A**, **B**, and **C**.

In a  nutshell, Activity A starts Activity B, then A also starts Activity C and expects a result from C, but never gets it.

Here is the application workflow:

1. Activity A is launched on app startup and starts Activity B (not for result, just startActivity()) in onCreate.

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class));
   }
   ```
2. Activity A then also starts Activity C later in code, this time for result using startActivityForResult(), and Activity A also has onActivityResult.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
   ```

   and

   ```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Activity C uses setResult() and finish() to return some data, which should go back to Activity A, because Activity A called startActivityForResult().

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("encryption", encryption);
   setResult(56, intent);
   finish();
   ```

**BUT** the workflow falls silent at step 3 - Activity A's onActivityResult is never called (neither is B's for that matter), even though Activity A is the one starting C for result. Not sure if Activity B is getting in the way of A and C's communication or what the problem could be. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: its so difficult to understand ....Activity B then uses Activity A to make a web service call, and if Activity A determines a login is necessary, it starts Activity C

Comment: Edited question to simplify it. Basically Activity A starts Activity B, then A also starts Activity C and wants a result from C, but never gets it.

Comment: startActivityforresult come in B activity its work from which activity you start and come back on onactivityresult

Comment: I'm calling startActivity in A to start B, and startActivityForResult in A to start C, so C should return result to A.

Comment: ya definately give onActivityResult method in A

Comment: onActivityResult is in A, but it never gets called when C finishes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8833/discussion-between-samir-and-guddie)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was never able to get this to work, so I ended up using a Handler instead to return the data to the necessary Activity.

**UPDATE**: After running into this again, I found out that the real reason this wasn't working is because I had `android:noHistory="true"` for the calling/receiving Activity A in the manifest. Removing `android:noHistory="true"` fixed it, but if you need it to be true, then Handlers are a good workaround.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out why onActivityResult wasn't being called and this was the reason. I've logged an Android documentation issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68137.

Comment: @Vicki 13 months later this issue still states "New". Somehow Android sucks in too many areas. Documentation is certainly one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use `getApplicationContext()` in the intent.

From the developer website.

```
getApplicationContext()
Return the context of the single, global Application object of the current process.
```

When you you `startActivityForResult()` it tries to return to the activity specified in the intent, which you are providing as the global application context.

If you have an ActivityB then you should call it like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then it will try to return to ActivityB when ActivityC is done.

Comment: I thought that the activity the result is returned to is the activity that called startActivityForResult(), not the Context specified when creating the Intent. Regardless, changing it as you specified still did not return the result to onActivityResult.

Comment: Clarification, if the last 2 lines of code are called from ActivityB. ActivityC is started then returns to ActivityB, it doesn't answer you original question more to illustrate the correct parameters to use when creating an intent. Perhaps adding a more complete example of your code where you start the Activities may be helpful.

Comment: In my scenario, your last 2 lines of code are called from Activity A, which is where I want the result to be returned to. But it isn't happening, and the only thing I can determine is that it be because Activity A also starts Activity B first.

Comment: Are you saying you start ActivityB from ActivityA then immediately after start ActivityC from ActivityA?

Comment: Yes. Activity B is started with startActivity and C is started with startActivityForResult, because I want A to get C's result.

Comment: You shouldn't be starting activities one after another, you need to start AcivityB do whatever you need to there then return to ActivityA then start ActvityC. Like I said earlier, a more complete code sample would help to where the problem is.

Answer (score -2):

You might give this a try:

```
if (getParent() == null) {
setResult(RESULT_OK, dataTobePassback);
} else {
getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, dataTobePassback);
}
```

`dataTobePassback` is an `Intent` that carries the stuff you may need to pass back to the calling activity

Comment: Would be interesting to know why/how this should work.