# Nested startActivityForResult() not returning to previous Activity(s)

Tags: android

I know this is similar to another post, but that was never really answered.

It's using Activity and not Fragments, and isn't using ActivityGroup
or Tabs.

My MainActivity calls LocationActivity with startActivityForResult
which later calls DialogActivity with startActivityForResult,
but when DialogActivity exits and uses setResult and finish
the onActivityResult in LocationActivity is never called, it goes
all the way back to the onActivityResult in MainActivity.

All the Activity properties are "blank", noHistory is false by default.

```
(MainActivity)
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     LocationActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.LOCATION_ACTIVITY);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int iRequestCode, int iResultCode, Intent intentData)
{
    super.onActivityResult(iRequestCode, iResultCode, intentData);
}

(LocationActivity)  
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.DIALOG_ACTIVITY);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int iRequestCode, int iResultCode, Intent intentData)
{
    super.onActivityResult(iRequestCode, iResultCode, intentData);
}

(DialogActivity)    
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

So what do I need to change to get the onActivityResult in LocationActivity
to get called after the DialogActivity exits, and not the onActivityResult
in MainActivity?  And, after I exit LocationActivity, I'd like for
the onActivityResult in MainActivity to finally get called.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add these activities declaration from manifest?

Comment: Did you have a look on this discussion ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689001/activity-started-with-startactivityforresult-not-returning-to-calling-activity?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I just did.  I changed the Context to use the Activity name, and that didn't work,  and I don't have any Activity properties set to use noHistory true

Answer (score 0):

I guess yuo create both intents with the same context. Try use this(current activity) instead of getApplicationContext().

Comment: Just tried changing the Intents to use:  MainActivity.this and  LocationActivity.this and the same thing happens, the onActivityResult() in MainActivity keeps getting called, thanks though..

Comment: <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <activity android:name=".DialogActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LocationActivity" />                  Also, looking at the Logcat, I noticed that onPause() onStop() and onDestroy() are called after I call the startActivityForResult() in LocationActivity..

Comment: Where does LocationActivity calls setResult() and finish(). onActivityResult() is called even after onResume(). So your activity can finish() itself before getting result.

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem.  After LocationActivity calls startActivityForResult() it falls through and eventually calls setResult() and finish(), exiting.  I commented out the setResult() and finish() code, and now the LocationActivity onActivityResult() gets called from the DialogActivity!