# Return to Activity after opening Gallery Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alertdialog, android-gallery

I'm creating an app that involves setting up a profile picture, I based my code on tutorials and the code opens the gallery, I'm able to select the picture but I don't understand why it doesn't come back to the activity when I select it.

Note, all of this happens on an AlertDialog.

```
public class ChangePhotoDialog{
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private View dialoglayout;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    private Firebase mRef;

    public ChangePhotoDialog(Activity a, final SettingsFragment myFrag, final User user){
        LayoutInflater inflater = a.getLayoutInflater();
        dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.change_picture, null);

        mRef=new Firebase("https://custom.firebaseio.com/users/"+user.getUserId());

        //Retrieves elements on the change profile picture dialog box
        ImageView oldProfilePicture = (ImageView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.prev_photo);
        final ImageButton newProfileCamera = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.photofromcamera);
        final ImageButton newProfileGallery = (ImageButton) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.photofromgallery);

        oldProfilePicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.userdefault);
        //setup dialogue box
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(a);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                System.out.println("Operation Canceled");
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                System.out.println("Name Changed");
            }
        });

        newProfileCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(myFrag.getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    myFrag.getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
                }

            }

        });

        newProfileGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                myFrag.getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }


        });

    }

    public void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            String imagefile = encodeToBase64(thumbnail, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);

            //Push changes to firebase
            Map<String, Object> changes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            changes.put("profilePicName", imagefile);
            mRef.updateChildren(changes);

            ImageView oldPicture = (ImageView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.prev_photo);
            oldPicture.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }

    public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public void show() {
        alertDialog = builder.show();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that OnActivityResult would be called after the picture is selected from the Gallery but that does not happen. How can I fix this??

Thank you, if more information is needed let me know

Comment: Do you have `android:noHistory="true"` added to the calling activity in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, changed to false but still doesn't work.

Comment: Too bad. An other guy has managed to solve the problem with this change. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9794702/3572108).